# iMac goes black, makes clicking sound... thoughts?

Tags: macos, mac

This is the second time this has happened. The display on my Apple iMac (20-inch Late 2006)
just went black, system was completely unresponsive to mouse/keyboard input, I could not SSH into nor ping the machine, and it didn't show up in ARD. I could hear a fairly loud clicking noise from inside which sounded like the DVD drive trying to seek -- but there is no disc in the drive. It could possibly be the hard drive... I pressed the power button and the system powered off, and now will not power on again. Thoughts / suggestions as to next course of action?

**EDIT:** I unplugged the system and let it cool off, and after a few minutes I plugged it back in. As soon as power was restored it booted up (which wasn't what I wanted -- I wanted to run disk checks first...) I am running Apple Hardware Test now.

**EDIT2:** In the middle of the 5th pass of AHT, the system locked up in the middle of the memory tests. I am beginning to suspect a serious hardware problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a broken logic board, but you'll need to get a Genius to look at it.

Comment: Ugggg... That makes me very sad :-( A hard drive I can afford to replace, a logic board may be a different story. Would the Apple Hardware Test DVD diagnose this do you think? I'm going to try running that if I can get the system to boot again.

Comment: Well on the 7th pass of AHT it froze up on "Testing main logic board" which is right after testing memory. So I am afraid you're probably correct...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like a fan problem, simply due to the clicking sound. However there is a decent chance there is also a damaged sensor simply because of heat buildup.